# Fill template / model pdf from android application

Tags: android, pdf, crystal-reports, report, pdf-generation

I need to know if there is a possibility to have multiple templates/models pdf and if an android application can fills all fields and generate pdf with all data.

I try to find some information about Crystal Reports by SAP Business Objects, but apparently I can't do it.

It would be amazing if i can generate my Crystal Reports templates / models, load them on my android application, select the report to generate, fill all fields with my data and shows the pdf output.

Is it possible? There is some documentation and/or example?
There is some alternative over Crystal Reports?